# Matrix derivate of $ \sum_{rq}{{W}_{rq}{({G{G}^T})}_{rq}^2}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have two matrix euqation

(1) $Z(G) = \sum_{rq}{{W}_{rq}{({G{G}^T})}_{rq}^2}$. And I want to get
$\frac{\partial Z(G)}{\partial {G_{rq}}}$

(2) $Z(G) = \sum_{rpq} {W}_{rp}G_{pq}G_{rq}$. And I want to get
$\frac{\partial Z(G)}{\partial {G_{rq}}}$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$\eqalign{
 &A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB) = \sum_{ij} A_{ij}B_{ij} \cr
 &A\circ B \cr
}$$
denote the trace/Frobenius and elementwise/Hadamard products, respectively.

For convenience, define a new matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
  A &= GG^T \cr
 dA &= dG\,G^T+G\,dG^T \cr
}$$
Write the first function in terms of $A$, then find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 Z &= W:A\circ A \cr
dZ &= 2W:A\circ dA \cr
 &= 2W\circ A:dA \cr
 &= 2W\circ(GG^T):(dG\,G^T+G\,dG^T) \cr
 &= 2(W+W^T)\circ(GG^T):dG\,G^T \cr
 &= 2\Big((W+W^T)\circ(GG^T)\Big)G:dG \cr
\frac{\partial Z}{\partial G} &= 2\Big((W+W^T)\circ(GG^T)\Big)G \cr\cr
}$$
For the second function 
$$\eqalign{
 Z &= W^T:A \cr
dZ &= W^T:dA \cr 
 &= W^T:(dG\,G^T+G\,dG^T) \cr
 &= (W+W^T):dG\,G^T \cr
 &= (W+W^T)G:dG \cr
\frac{\partial Z}{\partial G} &= (W+W^T)G \cr
}$$

Comment: That 's really nice. Can you also recommend some material or textbook for me about such kind of matrix derivative? Thanks.